# How to apply auth middleware to graphql endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, graphql

I have a graphql endpoint in my node app which I want to wrap in an auth middleware to validate and extract a JWT. However, want some queries / mutations (i.e. register and login) to be public and the rest to be protected.

I have a simple server with a mixture of `express` and `apolloServer`:

```
const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3042;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`) )

export default app
```

I was thinking I would use passport to set a strategy to extract and validate the JWT and user and apply the `authMiddleware` to the apolloServer or `/graphql` endpoint.

```
passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey   : JWT_SECRET
  },
  (jwtPayload, cb) => {
    return UserModel.findOne({email: jwtPayload.email})
      .then(user => {
        return cb(null, user);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return cb(err);
      });
  }
));

const authMiddleware = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })
```

This works for a rest API where you can apply the middleware to the routes you need but I only want this to run on certain mutations / queries.

How do you handle validating / extracting JWT's in your graphql API?